# Outlook add-in get contact on the current view

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I am creating the following add-in for outlook:

[image]

It is composed of:

1. Ribbon1. (note how the ribbon type is Microsoft.Outlook.Contact) Thats why plugin will only appear on contacts.

[image]

2. That ribbon has a RibbonTab and that ribbon tab has a RibbonGroup and inside that group I have a button called button1.

**How can I get a reference to that contact when I click on the button?**

This is what I have tried:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Clicked");

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application a = new Application();

        var currentView = a.ActiveExplorer().CurrentView;

        // now how do I get the currect contact from the current view?
        // currentView.ContactItem shows an error
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Clicked");

        var item = this.Context as Inspector;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        var contactItem = item.CurrentItem as ContactItem;
        if (contactItem != null)
        {
            // current contact on view
            Console.WriteLine(contactItem.BusinessFaxNumber);
        }
    }
```